# Find any of a set of substrings in a string efficiently

Tags: string, algorithm, substring

Suppose we have 3 strings: `"ab", "cd" and "ef"`.
Let us suppose the substring we want to search for is a permutation of the above strings, 
 i.e. `any of {"abcdef","abefcd","efabcd","efcdab","cdefab","cdabcf"}`

 Now let us suppose we have a long string and we want to find any of the substrings from the above set in it (simplifying the case a little and assuming theres only one occurrence of only one of those substrings in the main string).

eg.

```
Main string: abcdghefcdabgh
Substring:         efcdab
```

What will be the most efficient way to do the search in this case ? Doing a brute force and searching for each possible substring is highly inefficient. 
Rabin-Karp for multiple-pattern search is one method that comes to my mind. However I am not sure what would an very efficient hash function be in that case.

Comment: What's wrong with the Rabin-Karp rolling hash described by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash)?

Comment: For the specific case you describe, it doesn't seem all that inefficient to check each substring of the search string of the desired length (there are O(n) of them for search string length n) and see whether this is a target string. If the target string set is small, you can build a hash table in O(m) (where m is the number of target strings)... Otherwise, you could construct some kind of search tree or something. I don't know how you think you can do this better than O(n + m)... sorry for being dense if this misses something obvious.

Comment: @robmayoff well theres nothing wrong with it. I just want to know is there a better method that I'm missing :)

Comment: @Patrick87 well this was a question on interviewstreet's facebook challenge. The case i described is a very small one. The question said the string to be searched in could be a million characters long and the number of substrings that could be chosen from are 100! (here it is 3!)

Answer (score 1):

search for any "ab", find either "cd" or "ef" at +1 or -1, continue until whole permutation is found.

example:

using `"ab", "cd", "ef"`
in `"asjkdnjdnaboidnabefcdasdnmk"`

first instance of `"ab"` is at `9`, thus:

```
lowerFound = 9
upperfound = 11 \\ found index + length of found string
```

from there you know that any other match in the permutation has to either be before the `lowerfound` or above the `upperfound`, thus look on both sides, for this example:
`dn ab oi` does not contain any matches, thus discard and find the next `"ab"` at `15`

```
lowerFound = 15
upperfound = 17
search for "cd" or "ef" at 15-length or 17
found "ab"+"ef"

lowerFound = 15
upperfound = 19
search for "cd" at 15-length or 19
found "abef"+"cd"

return
```

I have formulated a program to do this, but it is quite large, line wise, so i've put it [right here](http://pastebin.com/5tD3rHA5), feel free to critic this approach.
To reduce the worst case `"ababababababababcdef"` you may like to keep index's already searched in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if finding all the permutations of the pattern strings is an option, but if these permutations can be found in a reasonable amount of time, then you can use this algorithm, to check for all the patterns simultaneously.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm

Another quicker method which will require some extra space, would be to construct a suffix tree on the Text. And then match each of the patterns.
Making the tree is O(n) where n is the Text size.
Matching each pattern is O(p) where p is the length of each pattern.

Total time = O( p1 + p2 + p3...  + n )